# reorder nodelist in java

Tags: java, live, nodelist

i am trying to reorder a nodelist generated by an xpath expression. 
I have manged to do this by copying all the nodes in the list one by one to a new document (in any order) and using the getChildNodes method to return it as a node list. However, I want the nodes in the new list to keep the structure of the original nodes so that if I run, for example,  getParentNodes() on a node in the new node list, I will get the parent node from the original xml.

Here is some code that shows in general what i am trying to do:

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import org.w3c.dom.*;
    import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
    import javax.xml.parsers.*;
    import javax.xml.xpath.*;

    public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws SAXException, IOException, XPathExpressionException, ParserConfigurationException { 

  String xmlStr="";
  String xpathStr="";

    //run standard xpath expression that returns a nodelist
      DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true); 
      DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
      Document doc = builder.parse(xmlStr);

      XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
      XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
      XPathExpression expr= xpath.compile(xpathStr);

      Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
      NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;

       /*i need to reorder the node list so i created a secondary doc,
       * and copied the nodes there one by one in the required order*/

      //create second doc 
      DocumentBuilderFactory factory1 = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      DocumentBuilder builder1 = factory1.newDocumentBuilder();
      Document nodeListDoc = builder1.newDocument();

      //create root element for the new doc 
      Element root = (Element) nodeListDoc.createElement("rootElement");

      for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
          //import node to new doc
          Node newNode=nodeListDoc.importNode(nodes.item(i),true);
          //insert node into tree
          root.appendChild(newNode);

          //original node shows the correct parent from the xml
          System.out.println("original: "+nodes.item(i).getParentNode());
          //new node shows root/null as parent
          System.out.println("new: "+newNode.getParentNode());

      }

      //save as new nodelist
      NodeList nodeListOrdered= root.getChildNodes();


  }
```

}

Comment: it's not clear !! could you specify what you want ? what you've tried ? and what's the problem with what you've done !

Comment: i tried making it clearer. The problem is that the copied node no longer references the xml so methods on it return null.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question isn't clear in its current form, and would be better explained with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to accompany it that would allow us to reproduce your problem. You should also specify which library you're using for the `Node` implementation, since there are several implementations, including a Java default and a number of other `xml-api` libraries that implement the W3C interface standards.

Comment: i have restructured the question and provided code that compiles. I understand why the node copies have a different parent but the question is, what can i do so that they still reference the xml?